# Upgraded Parallels to 10.2.0 (28956) disabled bluetooth connectivity

Tags: macos, bluetooth, parallels

Until upgrading I was able to connect with Bluetooth and BLE devices on Parallels virtual machines by checking the "Apple Bluetooth USB Host controller" option in the Parallels tool. I can still check it, but for some reason I can no longer see to connect to any bluetooth or BLE devices.

Also, if you have any advise how to downgrade Parallels to a version prior to current I assume it can be of use.

I run Parallels over Mac OS 10.9.5

Thanks,
Asaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning to Parallels, alas yields no reply. So I turned to a friend. Here's what worked for me to enable bluetooth and BLE connectivity in a Parallels virtual machine:

1. Turn off sharing of Bluetooth devices in the hardware settings of the Parallels tools

[image]
2. Turn on Apple Bluetooth USB Host Controller for list of devices

[image]

And that's it, basically. You can restart the virtual machine to see the bluetooth icon on the top status bar of your virtual machine but basically - problem solved. Hope this helps someone.